# Batch - Reg query + if exists doesnt work together?

Tags: batch-file, echo, registrykey

I have a piece of code I want to use

```
reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile /v EnableFirewall if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo On
```

This will check if the firewall is enable if so it will echo "On".
I try testing this command but my output is:

> ERROR: Invalid syntax.
>   Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.

Does anybody knows how to let this code work?

- Luseres

Comment: I don't think the `reg query` command writes the value of a registry key in the `errorlevel` environment var. I think you should use a `for` to parse the output of the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `for` you can do something like:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile /v EnableFirewall') do (
    if "%%i" equ "0x1" (
        echo activated
    ) else (
        echo not activated
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you @dcg, is there also a way to make a %firewall% vairable on the activated / not activated output?

Comment: @Luseres Instead of printing you can create a variable like so `set "firewall=activated/not activated"`.

Comment: Thank you @dcg I like that you wanted to help me!